# Interpretation of odd Central Limit Theorem (i.i.d) condition

Tags: probability, convergence, central-limit-theorem

My class was taught a third sufficient condition for the CLT to hold in the i.i.d. case that can replace the Lindeberg or Lyapunov conditions. I have never seen this condition before and am wondering how it could be interpreted (and whether it has a name):

$$\max_{i\leq n}E\{(X_i - \mu_i)/S_n\}^2 \rightarrow 0 \space \text{as} \space n \rightarrow \infty $$

The way I interpreted is that the maximum squared deviation any observation can have converges will pale in comparison with the variance, but I am fairly sure that this is not quite what the statement means.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you state precisely the CLT in question? The stated condition cannot be meant for a CLT under i.i.d. assumption.

Comment: You're right, I missed that the identical distribution is missing. The precise formulation is: 
Let $(X_i)_{i\in N_0}$ be independent distributed with expectations $\mu_t$ and variances $\sigma_i^2$. Let $S_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2$. If one of the following conditions holds (lists Lindeberg, Lyapunov, and above mentioned condition). Then, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu _i)}{\sqrt{S_n^2}} \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,1)$$